# If Command/Order same as previous then stop current script

Tags: php, html

I have a simple project that's maybe easy for you.
My Project is to create a chat application.
I successfully created it but I have a problem. My Problem is that every time I reload the page, the text is repeated.

I use a database to save chat history including name, website and text.

The script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include"config.php"; //This is my database config and connection file
if ( isset ($_POST['nama'])) {
    $nama = $_POST['nama'];
    $web = $_POST['website'];
    $isi = $_POST['pesan'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO history(nama, website, text) VALUES('$nama', '$web', '$isi')";
    mysql_query($query); }
    $tampil = "SELECT * FROM history";
    $hasil = mysql_query($tampil);
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil)) {
       echo"<a href='".$data['website']."'>".$data['nama']."</a>" : ".$data['text']."<br />"; }
?>
```

Anyone knows how to stop the previous chat? I mean I open `chat.php` (My index) and I input the name, website and text and I click the send button. The chat appears and I reload it with f5. The chat appears again with same as previous even the input is blank.

I'm sorry for my bad english. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When clicking submit you issue an POST request to your webserver. which tells him to add your message to the history table. Every time you press F5 again, the same POST request is sent to the server. And again it is telling your server to add that same message to your history table.

The solutions is simple. What you want to do is that the browser performs a NEW request to your chat.php. A request that doesn't have set the nama variable. After this new request all F5 presses will trigger this new request and not the old one.

You can do it by redirecting the browser to the proper URL using http headers.

Code example (not tested!):

```
if ( isset ($_POST['nama'])) {
    $nama = $_POST['nama'];
    $web = $_POST['website'];
    $isi = $_POST['pesan'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO history(nama, website, text) VALUES('$nama', '$web', '$isi')";
    mysql_query($query); 

    // NOW FORCE THE BROWSER TO ISSUE A NEW REQUEST
    header('Location: chat.php');
}
```

Be sure to use the correct link for your chat.php file.